# Как сделать, чтобы скрипт jQuery срабатывал через определённое время?

Tags: javascript, jquery, таймер

У меня есть код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let qtySlides = $('.slider>div').length-1;
    let slider=$('.slider').slick({
        arrows: false,
      dots: true,
      speed: 300,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2500,
      infinite: false,
      pauseOnHover: false
    });
    slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    if( qtySlides === slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide') ){
      slider.slickSetOption("autoplay",false,false)
    };
  });
    });
```

Как сделать, чтобы он срабатывал через 5000мс после загрузки страницы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто заверните всё это в [setTimeout](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

```
setTimeout(() => {
  let qtySlides = $('.slider>div').length-1;
    let slider=$('.slider').slick({
        arrows: false,
      dots: true,
      speed: 300,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2500,
      infinite: false,
      pauseOnHover: false
    });
    slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    if( qtySlides === slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide') ){
      slider.slickSetOption("autoplay",false,false)
    };
  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: спасибо, а я пытался как-то так сделать: $(function(){          
  $('.slider').delay(5000)
  .show(1000);
});